# C Static Library(.lib) to be used on a C DLL

Tags: c, dll, static-libraries, libusb-1.0

Hi I'm trying to create a dll of my C program, my program sends and receives messages to a usb device. I'm using libusb1.0 as a library for my C Program. Now that I want to make my program into a dll to be usable by other programs, I can't imagine how to import or bundle my dll with the libusb.

So researching on my problem, I found that libusb provides a static library and I've seen articles about linking static libraries on a DLL using C++.

So my question is... Is it possible to link a static library(.lib file) into a dynamic link library (.dll) in a C environment?

P.S. If it is possible can I ask links/tutorials to get me started on developing this?

Comment: Search for wrappers guide. Is usual to wrap [tag:c] .lib into, for example,  a [tag:c++] DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows a DLL is basically just a normal executable file with a special entry-point (`DllMain` instead of `WinMain` or `main`), and as any other normal executable you can use both static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: With that concept, my dll will call the static library. Then it is guaranteed that the programs that use my dll will work even without having the static library in their terminals?

Comment: @pejobear Simplified, a static library is nothing more than a collection of object files. Linking with a static library is like linking with the actual object files. And that's also kind of the point with static libraries, they are statically linked into the resulting executable/DLL, they become part of the executable/DLL.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.